# Swapping algorithm giving everything the same value

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

I have been given a task for my course to write a program which creates 52 card objects which each card has a value and a suit. After we create an array of the objects we have to switch the position of two cards at random. The problem is when I go to swap my cards that they both turn out to be the same. Here's the code that causes the problem:

```
void SwapCards(Card* cardOne, Card* cardTwo) {
    //swap cards here
    Card *temp = cardOne;
    *cardOne = *cardTwo;
    *cardTwo = *temp;
    //once it gets here all three variables end up with the same object?
}
```

Now here's the for loop that calls this function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 104; i++) { 
    //get two random values and send them to SwapCards to switch both objects
    int c_one = RandomRange(0, 51);
    int c_two = RandomRange(0, 51);
    SwapCards(deck[c_one], deck[c_two]);
}
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure it out but it just confuses me greatly.

Comment: Avoid pointers if you want references (and a value `temp`)

Comment: What is the type of `deck`?

Comment: @AnonMail He is actually dereferencing cardTwo and assign it to the derereferenced cardOne. The problem is that temp is not a copy of the card, but a pointer.

Comment: I guess they're not teaching `std::swap` ?

Comment: Not at this point, we're still only learning the core building blocks of c++ right now.

Comment: See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/swap/ then - it would be more usual to pass _references_ to the items you wish to swap rather than pointers.

Comment: `std::swap` is a core building block. Unfortunately many never get around to teaching these things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `*` from `temp` in `Card *temp = cardOne;`. Instead use

```
Card temp = *cardOne;
```

then

```
*cardTwo = temp;
```

Comment: Just have to wait a few minutes to be able to!

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok. Sorry. will amend.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think it is OK in this case: since Temunish said "Thanks you so much", we can assume that he accepts this as an answer, and since he is new to SO (judging from his rep), one can assume that he either forgot to accept it or didn't new about accepting answers at all. I saw a lot of good answers with "Thank you" messages but not accepted (even if it was the only answer for the question).

Comment: @Satus A hey you have never accepted an answer.  If this answers you might want to accept it is okay.  The original comment was basically *no problem.  accept this answer.*

Comment: @Temunish Well another sample of a help vampire OP, accepting the first answer that gets their code working, without caring for any explanation, or what could probably improved. Sigh!

Answer (score 5):

> *"The problem is when I go to swap my cards that they both turn out to be the same."*

You are loosing the current value of `cardOne` here:

```
*cardOne = *cardTwo;
```

Since `temp` still points to the same address as `cardOne`, `cardOne`'s original value was not saved with it.

Change your code as follows, to save `cardOne`'s value:

```
Card temp = *cardOne;
*cardOne = *cardTwo;
*cardTwo = temp;
```

---

The even better (and probably clearer) solution would be to use references instead of pointers:

```
void SwapCards(Card& cardOne, Card& cardTwo) {
    //swap cards here
    Card temp = cardOne;
    cardOne = cardTwo;
    cardTwo = temp;
}
```

And as a side note: This is what [`std::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) would already do, no need to roll your own implementation here.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to write a "swap" function in C++ is to pass *references* instead of pointers:

```
void swap(Card &a, Card &b)
{
    Card tmp(a);  // or Card tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}
```

There's no need to call the function `swapCard` because parameter matching means it can only ever be invoked with two `Card` arguments.

This can then be made almost completely generic using templates:

```
template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b )
{
    T tmp(a);  // construct a copy of a
    a = b;     // overwrite 'a'
    b = c;     // replace 'b' with the copy
}
```

This is such a common paradigm that it became standard - `std::swap`.

If the type `T` is compatible it "just works", otherwise you can implement a "specialization" of the template for a specific class.  It's sometimes desirable to specialize for efficient reasons (e.g. you can swap member pointers instead of copying their contents).

Comment: I agree, but it's a homework assignment and I assume that pointers are part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the function, `cardOne` points to one card and `cardTwo` points to another card.

```
 Card *temp = cardOne;
```

`temp` now points to the card that `cardOne`points to.

```
 *cardOne = *cardTwo;
```

The card that `cardOne` points to now has the same value as the card that `cardTwo` points to.

```
 *cardTwo = *temp;
```

The card that `cardTwo` points to now has the same value as the card that `temp` points to, which is the same card that `cardOne` points to – the card that you just gave the same value as the card `cardTwo` points to.
In other words, this assigns to `*cardTwo` the same value as `*cardTwo` already has.

For swapping, you want to save the value of `*cardTwo`, not its address.

```
Card temp = *cardOne;
*cardOne = *cardTwo;
*cardTwo = temp;
```